# How long does it take for King Stropharia to colonize cardboard?

Tags: mushrooms

I recently put in a cardboard bed of King Stropharia, and was wondering what growth rates I'm looking at to get successful colonization to rip it apart, and get more material going.

I love mathematical formulas.

Comment: I thought you might be a math wizard.  Gardening and math go hand in hand except math and gardening won't easily be recognized as going together.   Black thumb, your gardening gives you a break from 'being in control'.  If I were you I would do your King on cardboard and then just allow another piece of cardboard to be moisturized and leave it be.  Oh, some regular warmth.  Math is constant but does not help with gardening unless you are able to free form.  Math won't help you grow plants but math is part of all processes, we just are unable to understand how to recognize math making gardens.